# Unable to start class in php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm doing a PHP form with ajax but having trouble initializing a class ou classes. I think the problem is with the path, I have a addproduct.php with this form, i don't believe posting the form will help beacause it isnt getting any error, but if you think it is, let me know so i can post it.

[Infrastructure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqCFr.png)

This is where i submit the form (posproduct.js)

```
$(document).on('submit', '#product_form', function(){
    
    var $form = $('#product_form');
    var dados = $form.serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form.php',
        async: true,
        dataType: "html",
        data: dados
    }).done(function(msg){
         window.location.href = "index.php";
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, msg){
         alert(dados);
         console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, msg);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here i enter in this try catch but dont get this error, only if i take out the "//" (form.php)

```
<?php 
    //require_once("config.php");
    include_once('/class/Book.php');
    include_once('/class/DVD.php');
    include_once('/class/Forniture.php');

    saveProduct();
    function saveProduct(){
        $ok = 0;

        try {
            //http_response_code(405);
            $book = new Book();
            http_response_code(405);
            $book->setDescription($size);
            $book->setSku($sku);
            $book->setName($name);
            $book->setPrice($price);
            $book->setType($type);
            $book->insert();

            http_response_code(401);
            //$ok += 1;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //echo "$e";
        }
```

My Book Class

```
<?php
include_once('/class/Product.php');

class Book extends Product
{
    public function setDescription(int $value)
    {
        $this->description = $value;
    }
}
 ?>
```

My product class

```
<?php 
include_once('DAO.php');
abstract class Product
{
    protected $sku;
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $type;
    protected $description;

    public function getSku()
    {
        return $this->sku;
    }

    public function setSku($value)
    {
        $this->sku = $value;
    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($value)
    {
        $this->name = $value;
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice($value)
    {
        $this->price = $value;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType($value)
    {
        $this->type = $value;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    abstract public function setDescription($value);

    public function insert()
    {
        $dao = new Dao();
        $result = $dao->query("INSERT INTO tb_produtos (sku, pname, price, ptype, pdescription) VALUES(:SKU, :NAME, :PRICE, :TYPE, :DESCRIPTION)", array(
            ":SKU"=> $this->getSku(),
            ":NAME"=> $this->getPname(),
            ":PRICE"=> $this->getPrice(),
            ":TYPE"=> $this->getType(),
            ":DESCRIPTION"=> $this->getDescription()
        ));
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        $dao = new Dao();

        return $dao->select("SELECT * FROM tb_produtos ORDER BY id;");
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return json_encode(array(
            "sku"=>$this->getSku(),
            "name"=>$this->getName(),
            "price"=>$this->getPrice(),
            "type"=>$this->getType(),
            "description"=>$this->getDescription()
        ));
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: try relative paths like this: ./class/... instead of /class

Comment: Hi
check these :
1. according to your photo, you dont have DVD.php & Forniture.php.
2. if you wnat to get a data via post in php you first need use code like this:
$size = $_POST['size'];
3. book class & product class are in same folder, you can use this code for include:
include_once('./Product.php');
4. about abstact class & functions please read this article:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_classes_abstract.asp

Comment: I didnt put the others classes because they are like book class. the relative paths didnt work. I think it is good to know that even without the response confirmation the .done method is called

Comment: just made another question related to this, hope you guys can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956615/mysql-column-names-and-php-class-with-different-name-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class Book in the function setDescription you declare the of the passing Value with int.  In Your astract Class you dont declare Type for Value. And php would throw an error. You can remove the type in the Book Class Method or add the type in the abstract class. But it's probably not meant to be int, is it? A string would be better.

**Change**
`public function setDescription(int $value)`
**to:**
`public function setDescription($value)`

Comment: i made it backwards but it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that is missing a "int" into abstract public function setDescription($value);